# remove the substring starting with some given characters

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

There are some strings with the following pattern `'{substring1}.{substring2}'`. I only want to keep the `substring1`.  For instance, for `e23.hd`, I only want to keep `e23`.

Here is a code for testing

```
a = 'e23.hd'
import re
re.sub(".*","",a)
a

e23.hd
```

I tried to use `.*` to represent the `.{substring2}`, it seems it does not work.

Comment: `.` in regexp means "any character", so you'll have to escape it. Try something like `"\..*"` to get rid of everything after the dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are there any reason you use regex? This can be solved without regex.
But if you really want to, here the regex way:

```
a = 'e23.hd'
import re
re.sub("\..*","",a)
print(a)
#'e23'
```

or without regex:

```
print(a.split(".")[0])
#'e23'
```

or without regex and if multiple "." are possible:

```
print(a.rsplit(".", 1)[0])
#'e23'
```

Comment: Rather than subbing out what you don't want, it might be easier (more performant/intuitive, possibly?) to match what you do want: `re.match(r"[^.]*", "e23.hd")`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I simply wanted to stick with the original question as close as possible.